# Merging specific data from matching values

Tags: excel, powerquery

in power query, I want to merge column 1 with specific values from column 2, but not all and matching the team_id. Any idea how to achieve this? In DAX I can do it with LOOKUPVALUE() but how to do it in power query?

Table2

```
team_id   teamName
1         TeamA
3         TeamB
12        TeamC
```

Table2

```
team_id       teamPlace      dateAdded
43            Amsterdam      11/01/2020
50            London         12/01/2020
1             New York       13/01/2020
```

Table1 or TableX

```
team_id   teamName      teamPlace
1         TeamA         New York
3         TeamB         null
12        TeamC         null
```

Comment: Doesn't Merge work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- Your first table (your label `Table2`) I have named `Table.1`
- Your second table (your label also `Table2`) I have named `Table.2`

and you want to obtain your 3rd table (your label `Table1 or TableX`)

You can use the following PQ code to do a Nested Join with a join kind of Left Outer.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table.1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"team_id", Int64.Type}, {"teamName", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table.2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"team_id",Int64.Type}, {"teamPlace", type text},{"dateAdded", type date}}),
    join = Table.NestedJoin(Source,"team_id", Source2, "team_id","teamPlace"),
    #"Expanded newCol" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(join, "teamPlace", {"teamPlace"}, {"teamPlace"})
in
    #"Expanded newCol"
```

[image]

From your comments below, it seems you are not interested in creating a merged table, but rather adding a column to your existing first table.

For that, all you need to do is add a column to the table, and use the `VLOOKUP` formula.

Using the table naming scheme as above, the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[team_id]],Table.2,2,FALSE),"")
```

And the output would be the same as above

Comment: Hi, this works well but how can I add the column in my main table1 ? So not merging them in a new table. 
Btw I’m still using query’s so indoor have the table laid out. I want to mergy the values of the 2 query’s

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye If that's what you want to do, just use add a third column and use `VLOOKUP`.  eg `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[team_id]],Table.2,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm using power query.

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye I don't think you can actually **add** the column to your original table, and still maintain the integrity of the query using Power Query, but you should be able to place that column adjacent to the original table, in the `close and load to` dialog.